# PHP extensions dependency issue when installing from puppet

Tags: php, debian, vagrant, puppet

does anybody knows how to resolve issue with dependencies for php extensions ?

*default.pp*

```
class { 'php':
  package => 'php5',
  service => 'apache',
  version => '5.2.10.dfsg.1-2ubuntu6.5',
  require => Package['apache'],
}

package { "PhpModule_mhash":
  ensure   => '5.2.10.dfsg.1-2ubuntu6.5',
  name     => 'php5-mhash',
  require  => [Package['php'], Package['PhpModule_common'], ],
}
```

when i `vagrant up` i'm receiving `err`

```
err: /Stage[main]//Package[PhpModule_mhash]/ensure: change from purged to 5.2.10.dfsg.1-2ubuntu6.5 failed: Could not update: Execution of '/usr/bin/apt-get -q -y -o DPkg::Options::=--force-confold --force-yes install php5-mhash=5.2.10.dfsg.1-2ubuntu6.5' returned 100: Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
php5-mhash : Depends: php5 but it is not going to be installed or
                   phpapi-20060613+lfs
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
at /tmp/vagrant-puppet/manifests/default.pp:79
```

My virtual box repository is up to date and all required packages are available. PHP is also installed without problems.

What's very interesting is fact that when i `vagrant ssh` and execute following command:

`/usr/bin/apt-get -q -y -o DPkg::Options::=--force-confold --force-yes install php5-mhash=5.2.10.dfsg.1-2ubuntu6.5`

it's installed without any notice...

1. Is there a way to tell `Package` that php5 is already installed ?
2. Is there a way to omit dependencies if i have already required package ?
3. What options do i have on Puppet or Debian side?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puppet [Chaining](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/learning/ordering.html) is the answer !

Even though i've specified that *PhpModule_mhash* package`requires *php* class i had to insert chaining in my manifest.

```
Class['php'] -> Package['PhpModule_common'] -> Package['PhpModule_cli'] -> Package['PhpModule_mhash']
```